# iText 7 Java :cERROR com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader - Error occurred while reading cross reference table

Tags: java, itext7

I'm trying to read a pdf and copy it in a new pdf and add some text on it. 
My code is given below. The code worked and I get the new pdf with the new text. But I get those errors and I don't understand it.

````
```[main] ERROR com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader - Error occurred while reading cross reference table                                                                                                
Cross reference table will be rebuilt. com.itextpdf.io.IOException: Error at file pointer 284,030.
at com.itextpdf.io.source.PdfTokenizer.throwError(PdfTokenizer.java:686)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readXrefSection(PdfReader.java:1011)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readXref(PdfReader.java:944)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfReader.readPdf(PdfReader.java:677)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.open(PdfDocument.java:1871)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:252)
at com.itextpdf.kernel.pdf.PdfDocument.<init>(PdfDocument.java:234)
at Main.main(Main.java:52)                                                                      
Caused by: com.itextpdf.io.IOException: file position {0} cross reference entry in this xref subsection.
... 8 more```
````

My code :

```
    try {                                                                                
           //PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(), new PdfWriter());      
            PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter("01last.pdf").setSmartMode(true));
            PdfDocument srcDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader("diplome.pdf"));
            srcDoc.copyPagesTo(1, srcDoc.getNumberOfPages(), pdfDoc);

            Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);


            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            PdfFont normal = PdfFontFactory.createFont(FontConstants.TIMES_ROMAN);
            document.setFont(normal);
            Paragraph p = new Paragraph("Esdras ");
            Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph("Maxime ");

            document.showTextAligned(p, 50, 170,1,TextAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE,-11);
            document.showTextAligned(p2, 300, 170,1,TextAlignment.LEFT, VerticalAlignment.MIDDLE,-11);
            pdfDoc.close();



    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Please need your help. Sorry for my english. I trying hard to learn :)

Comment: Essentially that tells you that your pdf file is damaged and itext attempts to read it nonetheless.

Comment: Okay thank you i resolve it by changing the pdf file